# How can I have the bot interpret a certain string sent as an argument in a command and send an output of a converted version of that string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850806578125864981:
        return
    else:
      for arg in args:
        if arg == "g.basic":
          arg = "[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]"
      for arg in args:
        if arg == "g.drone":
          arg = "[68, .25, .1, .6, 4.97, .295/*.3*/, .96, 2.305, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1.1]"
    await ctx.send(args)
```

Let's say I type `!test [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.05, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] g.basic [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2] g.drone`

How can I get the bot to output `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.05, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2] [68, .25, .1, .6, 4.97, .295/*.3*/, .96, 2.305, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1.1]`?

The above code is my failed attempt to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please elaborate on what the functions are supposed to do? I can't tell based on your code at all

Comment: @Alyx Well, if arg is "g.basic" convert to "[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]"

Basically, try to visualize what I mean with the example I put under the code. Don't let the long number strings confuse you. They don't do anything special besides act as text that the bot is supposed to output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't 100% understand what you're going for, but you should make a empty list at the beginning, and append the number strings to it whenever the condition is met, then make it a string with:

```py
args = " ".join(args)
```

then you can return that, declaring

```py
if arg == x:
    arg = "y"
```

doesnt do anything if you don't touch the var "arg" you made, since thats not editing the list.